# If no posts in category display Form instead of not found

Tags: categories

I have a couple of categories that don't contain any posts (yet). What I would like to do is have a form which takes users details for future posts.

Am I right I thinking I simply edit the page which displays the current search bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your category.php ( or custom taxonomy archive template ), you should add the form code in the else case of your check if there are posts

e.g.

```
if(have_posts()){
    // do the post loop
} else {
    // display a form that takes user details for future posts
}
```

If there is no category.php you can copy and rename your index.php, and you can do the same for individual categories, e.g. category-example.php will be sued instead of category.php for the example category