# Display category description instead of "nothing found" page

Tags: categories, content, theme-twenty-fourteen

I'm using Wordpress 3.8.1 with the theme twenty fourteen. Unfortunately , when you click on a category with no post assigned to it for now , it displays a *not found* page. I've tried to create a plugins with a hook that replace that by a text (like the description of the category).

If there are no posts is in the category, only the description is displayed, if the category have posts, description is displayed and posts founds after. For now I don't find any ways to affect the *nothing found* page.

Is it possible to do this without modifying the category.php file (with plugin by hooks) like [this thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47379/if-no-posts-in-category-display-form-instead-of-not-found)

Comment: Pretty sure that the "nothing found" is actual text in the template file. It's not done with a function, hook or database info. You can probably hide that text with CSS if you don't want to see it. Or edit the template, there's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: I agree with @gdaniel. Why not create a child theme, takes less than 5 minutes, then copy category.php to your child theme and edit it as needed. The great thing is that if you need to modify something in the theme later, you will already have made a child theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a child theme. 
Copy category.php into your child theme. 
Comment out lines 17, 33, 46, 48, and 50. 
 
The category checks if you have any posts under that category and if not shows 'Nothing Found'. 
You're essentially removing the if statement. 
This will show the category title if there are not posts under this category.